# How we can show error message bad request 400 from Node.js express to react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

[image]

I want retrive the message "email exist already" in react when we get a bad request from server
my console show undefined.

Comment: Hola @Oussamaacey, I would suggest you to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And this: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html